# New In PYTHON 2

Tags: python-3.6

I posted few days ago and have tried to follow the suggestions.
I am sorry that I am not able to get it. Here are my questions:
1. When do I need to use FORWARD or back slash?[/ or ].
Please see what I have tried. There is a screen shot of my path and what the code and it still cannot find it...
I am so sorry tat this has not clicked. I have literally spent hours trying different things,
Thank you again[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRLQR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAzOb.png)

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Also, what specifically is the problem you're having? Are you trying to read from a file and it's not working? Are you getting an error somewhere in your code? This looks like more of a computer question if you're just asking when to use each type of slash.

Comment: Here you are using backward slash because you are working on Windows machine. Typically windows and Linux uses different slash for path. Windows uses backward slash while Linux uses forward slash. Since backward slash is used for escape sequence we have to use double slashes for providing path in windows.

Comment: okay and thank you all. I am sorry to make it so difficult, I promise I am a fast learner and will get this one way or the other.

Comment: okay and thank you all. I am sorry to make it so difficult, I promise I am a fast learner and will get this one way or the other. I am trying to read a File that is in my F drive and it cannot read it. . I am using Python and Spyder if that make sense and I use window. I am using window,,Here is the code {. # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

import pandas
import numpy

data = pandas.read_csv("F:\\ONLINEcourses\\DATA Analysis\\PYTHON\\Week1\\DATA\\2012_2016_PED.csv", low_memory=False) }          I am attaching my CSV file. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had that problem before when I first started using Python, I know the pain. If I am understanding your question correctly, you are asking which slash (/ or \) to use for an OS file-path. Luckily, you don't really have to care about which slash to use - it is generally discouraged to type the actual path in your code because it prevents portability.

I recommend using 
    `os.path.join()`. This will figure out which OS you are on and fill in the appropriate slash for you. You can pass individual arguments to this function or you can pass a list of strings.

For example `os.path.join('rootdir', 'dir', 'file')` will create the file-path (represented as a string) `rootdir\dir\file` (depending on your OS). This file-path can then be passed to whatever function you need a file-path for.

This is where you will find the documentation for `os.path`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: Thank you Bailey, I am ashamed to admit that your explanation intimidates me.I will try

Comment: Thank you Bailey for a clear explanation on the / Vs. \,Thank you again